# Group by with multiple date columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to do report for email status and I need to keep records on monthly basis.

Here is my table structure for data:

```
sent_on date;  
sent boolean;   
open date;  
clicked date;
```

The final output that I expect would be:

```
Month  | Year   | Sent Count | Open Count | Clicked Count
```

I know that I can do it if I make an individual statement such as

```
Select MONTH(sent_on), YEAR(sent_on), count(sent_on) FROM my_table
WHERE sent = true;

Select MONTH(open), YEAR(open), count(open) FROM my_table;

Select MONTH(clicked ), YEAR(clicked ), count(clicked ) FROM my_table;
```

Can you guys help me on this and provide any simple ideas? I'm sure I'm missing something. 
ps USING sql HERE

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: No, they are date. We needed to know WHEN the email was opened/clicked so we picked it as date.

Comment: @ Lieven We are using POSTGRESQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/51d8b/5)

```
select
    date_trunc('month', d) "month",
    count(sent and sent_on = d or null) sent_on,
    count(open = d or null) open,
    count(clicked = d or null) clicked
from
    t
    inner join
    generate_series(
        (select least(min(sent_on), min(open), min(clicked)) from t),
        (select greatest(max(sent_on), max(open), max(clicked))from t)
        , '1 day'
    ) s(d) on s.d in (t.sent_on, t.open, t.clicked)
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: @user Edited to make it group by month in instead of by day.

Comment: The `count` statements are wrong. `s.d in (t.sent_on, t.open, t.clicked)` will join the record with `s.d = '1/1/2013' sent_on = '1/1/2013' open ='2/2/2013'` and `count(open)` will count this record (`'2/2/2013'`) for period `'*/1/2013'`.

Comment: BTW. It might be better to generate on `1 month` interval and join on `date_trunc('month', sent_on), date_trunc('month', open), date_trunc('month', clicked)`

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarly performant code:

```
SELECT m, y, sent_count, open_count, clicked_count
FROM
    (SELECT MONTH(sent_on) as m, YEAR(sent_on) as y
    FROM my_table
    WHERE sent = true
    GROUP BY MONTH(sent_on), YEAR(sent_on)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH(open), YEAR(open) 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE sent = true
    GROUP BY MONTH(open), YEAR(open)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH(open), YEAR(open) 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE sent = true
    GROUP BY MONTH(open), YEAR(open)) d
LEFT JOIN 
(Select MONTH(sent_on) as m , YEAR(sent_on) as y, count(sent_on)  sent_count
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE sent = true
 GROUP BY MONTH(sent_on), YEAR(sent_on)) s on (s.y=d.y and s.m=d.m)
LEFT JOIN 
(Select MONTH(open) as m , YEAR(open) as y, count(open)  open_count
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE sent = true
 GROUP BY MONTH(open), YEAR(open)) o on (o.y=d.y and o.m=d.m)
LEFT JOIN 
(Select MONTH(clicked) as m , YEAR(clicked) as y, count(clicked)  clicked_count
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE sent = true
 GROUP BY MONTH(clicked), YEAR(clicked)) c on (c.y=d.y and c.m=d.m);
```

Supposed open and clicked are sent.

**UPDATE**: For performance we can start form folowing query:

```
Select MONTH(sent_on) sm, YEAR(sent_on) sy, 
       MONTH(OPEN) om, YEAR(OPEN) oy, 
       MONTH(clicked) cm, YEAR(clicked) cy, 
       count(sent_on) sent_cnt, count(clicked) clicked_cnt, count(open) open_cnt
FROM my_table
WHERE sent = true
GROUP BY MONTH(sent_on), YEAR(sent_on), 
       MONTH(OPEN), YEAR(OPEN), 
       MONTH(clicked), YEAR(clicked);
```

Comment: I was really trying to achieve this going through the table in one scan. Else as I stated in the parent comment, I would have done three different selects on it.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the dates, then group the results conditionally:

```
SELECT
  MONTH(eventdate) AS Month,
  YEAR (eventdate) AS Year,
  COUNT(CASE eventkind WHEN 'sent_on' THEN 1 END) AS SentCount,
  COUNT(CASE eventkind WHEN 'open'    THEN 1 END) AS OpenCount,
  COUNT(CASE eventkind WHEN 'clicked' THEN 1 END) AS ClickedCount
FROM (
  SELECT
    x.eventkind,
    CASE x.eventkind
      WHEN 'sent_on' THEN sent_on
      WHEN 'open'    THEN open
      WHEN 'clicked' THEN clicked
    END AS eventdate
  FROM my_table AS t
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('sent_on', 'open', 'clicked')) AS x (eventkind)
  WHERE t.sent = true
) AS s
GROUP BY
  MONTH(eventdate),
  YEAR (eventdate)
;
```